# How to use semantic-ui-react in visual studio ASP.NET Core project?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, reactjs, visual-studio-2017, semantic-ui

Say we have followed this [ReactJS.Net tutorial](https://reactjs.net/getting-started/tutorial.html) Now we want to add [semantic-ui-react](https://react.semantic-ui.com/usage)  to our React components so that they will look good. Yet there is no Bower or NuGet `semantic-ui-react` package, just `Semantic-UI` which does not help. So how to use semantic-ui-react on VS2017 with ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never used ReactJS.NET and not an expert on .NET but as I can understand from the docs you pointed out you can use [Webpack](https://reactjs.net/guides/webpack.html).

> Webpack is a popular module bundling system built on top of Node.js.
>   It can handle not only combination and minification of JavaScript and
>   CSS files, but also other assets such as image files (spriting)
>   through the use of plugins. Webpack can be used as an alternative to
>   Cassette or ASP.NET Combination and Minification. This guide assumes
>   you have already installed Webpack.

With this explanation we can assume that you can install `semantic-ui-react` with npm and configure Webpack so you can use components as described there.

```
@Html.React("Components.CommentsBox", new {
  initialComments = Model.Comments
})
```